# console.log shows original array after foreach

Tags: javascript

```
let words = ["[hello", "]bye", "", "lol-"];
words.forEach((item, index) => {
    item = item.replace(/\[|\]|\-/g, "");
    if (item == "") words.splice(index, 1);
});
console.log(words);
```

Why I always get `Array(3) [ "[hello", "]bye", "lol-" ]`?

I tried to `console.log` item after `replace()` and it returns correct item.

Comment: Have you try to use `.map` instead of `.forEach`? And what about `let words = words.forEach((item, index) => {` ?

Comment: replace does not change the original item, but creates a new one.

Comment: @AlexZeDim I tried both ways, none of them work. Can you show me example code? I don't think I have my trying right.

Comment: already two people below shows you the correct example. `.forEach` doesn't modify original array. `.map` does. You can read more about it here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Good blog on differences between forEach and map, complete with nice examples: https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f

In my own experience, understanding which methods modify the original array and which ones don't will save you headaches in the future. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forEach` only iterates through array. If you want to change elements of array use `map()` and to remove the empty string use `filter()`

```js
let words = ["[hello", "]bye", "", "lol-"];
words = words.map((item, index) => item.replace(/\[|\]|\-/g, "")).filter(x => x !== '');
console.log(words);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the third parameter of forEach to get source array:

```js
let words = ["[hello", "]by--e", "", "lol--"];
words.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
    arr[index] = item.replace(/\[|\]|\-/g, "");
});
words = words.filter(item => item);
console.log(words);
```

Comment: @bananabrann , thank you. it was because index increment during item removed. Fixed snippet

Answer (score 0):

The [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method doesn't modify the actual array. You should use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) methods to achieve your outcome.

```
let words = ["[hello", "]bye", "", "lol-"];
let updatedWords = words.map((item, index) => {
    item = item.replace(/\[|\]|\-/g, "");
    return item;
});

updatedWords = updatedWords.filter(word => word !== "");
console.log(updatedWords);
```